# How will delete the file using c#?

Tags: c#

I want to delete file using the delete function.

```
     foreach (string file1 in filePaths)
        {
            file = Path.GetFileName(file1);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                client = reader["name"].ToString();
                filename = reader[2].ToString();

                if (filename != file)
                    flag = 1;

                else
                    flag = 0;

            }
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(file);

                File.Delete(file);   

                data_count++;
            }


       }
```

My file is not deleting.

Comment: What happens if the file is not deleting? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Is there an exception? Did you set a breakpoint on File.Delete, to check if ther actually is a file that should be deleted?

Comment: increase your acceptance percentage

Comment: there is no exception and ihave set breakpoint and check so file is deleting but i am checking the location so file is exist there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you haven't given nearly enough information to really let us help you properly. What is your code *meant* to be doing?

I *suspect* that the problem is that your `flag` variable (which looks like it should probably be of type `bool` rather than `int`) is *entirely dependent* on the last iteration of your while loop. Basically your code currently says: "Delete the file if the final record in the reader talks about a different file."

Is that what you *wanted* it to say?

Note that the first iteration of the `foreach` loop is going to read from `reader` to completion... subsequent iterations will never read any more data, and indeed will use the existing value of `flag`. So you'll either end up deleting *all* the files or *none* of them. Again, I doubt that's what you actually want to do.

I *suspect* you should actually be reading from `reader` in one loop, building up a set of filenames, and then go through your "candidate" files in another loop. But without more information, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: actually i want to search file in sql server if its not present there so delete this file and write information in log file means which file is deleted.

Comment: @jiya: Right, so read all the files from SQL server, building up a list (or a `HashSet<String>` if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher) and then delete files which aren't in that set.